# PHP: Count values in Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have this Array:

```
array(66) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { 
    ["location"]=> string(10) "Breakwater" ["bsid"]=> string(4) "105a" 
  } 
[1]=> array(2) { 
    ["location"]=> string(10) "Breakwater" ["bsid"]=> string(4) "105b" 
  } 
[2]=> array(2) { 
     ["location"]=> string(10) "Breakwater" ["bsid"]=> string(4) "105c" 
  } 
[3]=> array(2) { 
    ["location"]=> string(10) "Breakwater" ["bsid"]=> string(4) "105d" 
  } 
[4]=> array(2) { 
    ["location"]=> string(10) "Breakwater" ["bsid"]=> string(4) "117b" 
  } 
[5]=> array(2) {
    ["location"]=> string(10) "Breakwater" ["bsid"]=> string(4) "117c" 
  } 
[6]=> array(2) { 
    ["location"]=> string(10) "Breakwater" ["bsid"]=> string(4) "123a" 
  } 
[7]=> array(2) { 
    ["location"]=> string(10) "Whateverelse" ["bsid"]=> string(4) "123b" 
  }
}
```

How can I count how many Breakwater's I have and how many Whateverelse's and get something like this:

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { 
      ["Breakwater"]=> string(2) "20" 
  } [1]=> array(2) { 
      ["Whateverelse"]=> string(1) "1"  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop around the original array, and each time a location is hit, increment a counter in the locations array where the index is the location.

```
$loc = array();
foreach($arr as $value) {
    $location = $value['location'];
    if(isset($loc[$location])) {
        $loc[$location]++;
    } else {
        $loc[$location] = 1;
    }
}
print_r($loc);
```

Will output

```
array
(
    ["Breakwater"] => 7,
    ["Whateverelse"] => 1
}
```

Comment: this is better than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this finally :

```
$output = array("Breakwater" => 0, "Whateverelse" => 0);

foreach ($array as $val) {
    $output["Breakwater"] += ($val["location"] == "Breakwater") ? 1 : 0;
    $output["Whateverelse"] += ($val["location"] == "Whateverelse") ? 1 : 0;
}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: In this case yes, but what if you have 10000 locations in your array? @Ryan's answer is universal, it works no matter how many records and locations are in array.

Comment: @ex3v, I agree, look at my comment on Ryan's answer